# Polymer: Custom elements' assets like images and stylesheets

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have a custom element which uses custom images. Folder structure of the custom element is as follows:

```
/custom-element
 --/images
   --image1.png
   --image2.png
 --custom-element.html
```

Now, when I run the default `gulp` task, my `images` folder is not exported along with the custom element. How to do that?